# Update Laravel column based on another column from the same query

Tags: laravel

I want to update all row that has no `'timemodified'` based on another column from the same query.

```
DB::table('sco_tracks')->where('timemodified', '')->update([
            'timemodified' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s' , DB::raw('updated_at'))->timestamp
        ]);
```

With this code I get: `Data missing {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): A four digit year could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the raw query would be

```
UPDATE sco_tracks t SET timemodified=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) WHERE timemodified IS NULL;
```

the code for laravel:

```
DB::table("sco_tracks")->where('timemodified','')->update(['timemodified'=>DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at)')]);
```

and if the value of timemodified field is null you can use this code:

```
DB::table("sco_tracks")->whereNull('timemodified')->update(['timemodified'=>DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at)')]);
```

Comment: Almost there, it works but I also want to edit  that date_time to timestamp, like in my example with Carbon, but I get "A four digit year could not be found"

Comment: have you tried SQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP function? I updated  my answer

Comment: In my case, whereNull is not working for some reason so I'm using where. But is perfect, thanks a  lot!